# How to use a different routeProvider depending on a section of your site

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Suppose I have multiple sections on my site, depending on someones role.

- /customer
- /manager
- /administrator

I wonder how I set up my Angular routes so that url's like this are possible:

- /customer
- /customer#/account
- /customer#/mybasket
- /manager
- /manager#/account
- /manager#/orders
- /administrator
- /administrator#accounts
- /administrator#settings

The "when" condition of the $routeProvider does only check on the url after the hash sign. How can you first reroute based on the first part of the URL? Or how to map a unique routeprovider per url (/customer, /manager, /administrator) ?

Comment: Create multiple modules, each representing distinct parts of your app that require different routing than others.

Comment: Use $stateprovider for distinct part of your app.

Answer (score 0):

The option you have is to use `html5Mode=true` and then get rid of the `#` altogether. But this requires handling full page refresh in which case the server need to return correct html.

This is from the [$location developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

> **Server side**
>
> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side,
> basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your
> application (e.g. index.html). Requiring a  tag is also
> important for this case, as it allows Angular to differentiate between
> the part of the url that is the application base and the path that
> should be handeled by the application.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished reading the new o'reilly book, by [Seshadri and Green, AngularJS up and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033486.do) and they talk about this extensively in Chapter 10.  the best descirption of ng-route so far for me.  This specific case is covered on p160-162.  Def. recommend the book for going deeper on angular.

A key concept to understand is that when the browser encounters the `#` in the url, it's a signal that says don't round trip to the server stay in the browser.  Because of this, any solution needs to have both server and client side code (e.g. if a user types in `http://foo.com/myfoo/mybar` your server has to know which file handles that route.

So at a high level, you need to do some server side stuff cooperatively with your client side angular code and use something called "HTML5 mode" and the browser's [push state api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).  I don't know what your doing server side; so i we leave that as a separate exercise; though its pretty simple in things like node,rails, and php to grab and manipulate the route on the server to have it return the right html file to handle the route.

As the book states, 3 steps, abbreviated here:

1. Enable HTML5 mode as part of the app config in your angular module.  that looks like this:

   ```
   angular.module('myapp',[ngroute])
      .config([$locationProvider','$routeProvider',
         function($locationProvider,$routeProvider){
             $locationProvider.html5mode(true);
     }]);
   ```
2. use the `<base>` tag within the `<head>` section to part of your name space your one page application will manage.  For example, if you are using something like angular-seed and it's in index.html in `/app` then the block looks like:

   ```
   <html>
     <head>
       <base href="/app" />
     </head>
   </html>
   ```

This is so the browser doesn't mangle the relative paths based on what you do.  So if index.html at /app handles /app/customer, /app/manager, and the like; this makes sure that if the user enters /app/customer/todd the index.html page relative links, for example /app/admin will start with /app instead of /app/customer/todd, and send /app/admin to your server instead of /app/customer/todd/admin.

3. On the server, you need to make sure that any of the sub urls redirect to the angular page that handles the subroute.   If you stated with something like angular-seed; moving to this sort of routing will require you to likely go away from the static web server it uses to an app specific node application.   A relatively simple express/nodejs app will insure that when the client requests /app/customer/todd it returns /app/index.html to process the request.

Worth reading the docs on [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) to understand more of how it's all put together.  I found [another example](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/angular/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag) on the web but it neglects talking about 3, which would cause a gotcha in a more complex scenario.  Its code snippet is more complete than I've put here; so probably worth the energy of the link traverse.

The book talks about other implications for SEO and such, as does [this post](http://vladimirfeskov.com/posts/angularjs-html5-mode-setup-use-and-seo); but this should get you started.